# Spacing views inside a compose row so the last view always is half shown

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a compose card and inside a row with circle views, I need to make it so the last item in this row is half shown only. Is there a easy way to achieve this without measuring the screen width after everything is drawn and then modify the padding for the row items dynamically to achieve it?)

[image]

Comment: Do you need this list of circles to be scrollable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to calculate the number of elements depending on the size of the cell contents, it is impossible to do this without real measurements.

But if you know exactly how many elements you need to display, you can use [`Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyItemScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillParentMaxWidth(kotlin.Float)) with the desired `fraction`. This is only available in lazy views like `LazyRow`.

Things are a bit more complicated with spacings: usually `contentPadding` is used to offset the first element, which reduces the `parent size`, depending on which `Modifier.fillParentPaxMaxWidth` calculates the actual value. Also, if you apply it to both `start` and `end`, you won't get the desired result. That's why I apply it only to `start`, and create an equivalent effect at the end with another `item`.

I also manually surround the `Spacers` item instead of using `Arrangement.spacedBy`, because the spacers should be inside the `Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth` too.

```
val spacing = 20.dp
val halfSpacing = spacing / 2
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(20)
LazyRow(
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = halfSpacing),
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(30.dp)
        .border(1.dp, color = Color.Black, shape = shape)
        .clip(shape)
        .padding(vertical = 20.dp)
) {
    items(10) {
        Row(
            Modifier
                .fillParentMaxWidth(1f / 3.5f)
        ) {
            Spacer(Modifier.size(halfSpacing))
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .aspectRatio(1f)
                    .background(Color.Blue, shape = CircleShape)
            )
            Spacer(Modifier.size(halfSpacing))
        }
    }
    item {
        Spacer(Modifier.size(halfSpacing))
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

`LazyColumn` variant:

```
val spacing = 20.dp
val halfSpacing = spacing / 2
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(20)
LazyColumn(
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = halfSpacing),
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(30.dp)
        .border(1.dp, color = Color.Black, shape = shape)
        .clip(shape)
        .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
) {
    items(10) {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillParentMaxHeight(1f / 3.5f)
        ) {
            Spacer(Modifier.size(halfSpacing))
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .aspectRatio(1f)
                    .background(Color.Blue, shape = CircleShape)
            )
            Spacer(Modifier.size(halfSpacing))
        }
    }
    item {
        Spacer(Modifier.size(halfSpacing))
    }
}
```