# Setting LazyColumn Item Height to Maximum Available in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I want to create a list of three boxes arranged in a `LazyColumn`. The height of the boxes should take up all the available space within the parent.

So if the parent has the height of 90dp and the bottom padding of the boxes is 5dp then the height of each box should automatically get calculated to be 25dp.

How to do this?

Note: I tried `modifier.fillMaxHeight()`, which doesn't seem to work for `LazyColumn` and `modifier.fillParentMaxHeight(1/3f)`, which does not include space for padding

Comment: I solved about the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70981692/3585796).

Comment: The idea of including Spacer in the parent and setting parent size to a fraction of the container was brilliant! Thank you. If you could put this in answer, I would mark the question as answered.

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate because the solution is essentially the same for `LazyColumn` and `LazyRow`. Still don't delete it, as people will be able to find the duplication link through your question.